# getting exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException while running this code?

Tags: java

I am getting an exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException while passing list[array.length] reference to s.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test
{
  public void demo(String [] list)
   {
   try
   {    
    String s=list[list.length];// error
   }
   catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException  e)
   {
  System.out.println("The exception is"+e);
   }
   finally
   {
      System.out.println("Finally here.");
   }
}
 public static void main(String [] args)
 {
   Test t=new Test();
   String [] list={"one","two"};
   t.demo(list);
   System.out.println("Done!");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have an array of length 5 you will have elements on the index 0-4 and you are trying to access the 5th element.

If you want to access the last element:

```
String s = list[list.length - 1];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String s=list[list.length];
```

arrays are indexed from 0 so last item is list.length-1

Answer (score 1):

**Index in most programming languages starts in zero.** So, you can use index in the range `[0, length - 1]`. But, in the line

```
String s = list[list.length];
```

you are using an invalid index. It should be (at max):

```
String s = list[list.length - 1];
```

Answer (score 1):

in Java arrays are zero based. so you have to write:

```
String s=list[list.length-1];
```

list.length gives you the number of elements in the array (2) but the last element in the array is on index 1

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the `Exception` due to the line :

```
String s=list[list.length];
```

Always remember :

```
Last-index_of_an_Array  = Array-length - 1 // because array index starts from 0
```

So, try :

```
String s=list[list.length - 1];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 String [] list={"one","two"};    
 list[0] value is "one";
 list[1] value is "two";
 list.length value is 2
 String s=list[list.length];// error
```

because

```
 String s=list[2];// error    
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```